Question regarding the vanishing of syndromes(excitations) in the boundaries of the symmetric rotated surface code
I've begun looking at Logical blocks for fault-tolerant topological quantum computation, and I've come across something in their diagrams of the XZZX code that is confusing me, in Fig 4.

They state that the primal and dual boundaries condense the excitations for the primal and dual strings. Which means that the parity for the stabilizers is being flipped, but the boundary is absorbing the syndrome for the end of the chain, just like in a regular surface code with rough and smooth boundaries. However, looking at their diagrams for the primal and dual boundaries, I can't see this. I can see why the excitation is created on the plaquettes, due to the non-commuting nature of the operator on them. I can see why no excitations (parity flips) occur for the other stabilizer in the path of the string, as it commutes with them. But as far as I can tell, given the stabilizers, weight 2, they have given for the boundaries, the error chains can't terminate in them as given.
In the first case, you have an $X$ error on the qubit that $Z$ acts on for the primal boundary stabilizers, giving $X_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$ which should change the parity, and in the second case, you have a $Z$ error on the qubit that $X$ acts on for the dual boundary stabilizer,giving  $Z_{2}Z_{1}X_{2}$. Additionally, as pointed out, these stabilizers, as given in the diagram, do not commute with the stabilizers at the sides of the lattice, and therefore wouldn't be stabilizers.
Additionally, the paper introducing The XZZX surface code code shows chains terminating in the boundaries differently,ie as one would expect, with a chain with a $Z$ errors at the end terminating by acting on the qubit of the 2 qubit boundary stabilizers acted on by the $Z$ operator, $Z_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$.
Otherwise, doing it there way, it shouldn't commute with the stabilizer. Unless I am missing something here.


Otherwise, doing it there way, it shouldn't commute with the
stabilizer. Unless I am missing something here.

Here I've written out the stabilizers at the boundary 
This shows that the errors commute with the stabilizers at the boundary.

In the first case, you have an $X$ error on the qubit that $Z$ acts on for the primal boundary stabilizers,$X_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$ which should change the parity, and in the second case, you have a $Z$ error on the qubit that $X$ acts on for the dual boundary stabilizer, $Z_{2}Z_{1}X_{2}$. Both stabilizers being identical in this case. ¨

I'm struggling to understand what you've written in this paragraph. There is no stabilizer of the form $X_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$ or $Z_{2}Z_{1}X_{2}$.

I'm a little confused by your answer. Are you saying that the paper has indeed placed the wrong stabilizers on the boundary, and the correct ones to cause the vanishing of excitations are the reverse order ones you've shown? Or I have misinterpreted the stabilizers at the boundary?

Also I see what happened with regards to the confusion regarding $X_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$. I phrased this badly. I wasn't saying $X_{1}Z_{1}X_{2}$ was a stabilizer, I was showing the action of the $X_{1}$ error on the stabilizer $Z_{1}X_{2}$, which would anti-commute and so not cause the excitiation to disappear. I have fixed this.

No I'm not saying the paper has placed the wrong stabilisers at the boundary. They have given the correct stabiliser.

Looking at the diagram, they have the opposite order for the boundary stabilizers. Do they get swapped/rotated as you move around the boundaries of the surface code? I can find no mention of this for the XZZX, beyond talk of a hadamard operation being applied, but the papers on it go very deeply into topological quantum order. Is it just that the stabilizers on the boundary on the other side are just equivalent to those on the top boundary up to hadamard operations, ie we take $Z_{1}X_{2}\to X_{1}Z_{2}$ via $H$?

$Z_1 X_2$ is not a stabilizer. It doesn't commute with the weight 4 stabilizers. You can see this in the figure I drew.

But they are stabilizers. As they give them in their diagram, $Z_{1}X_{2}$ is a stabilizer. I agree with you, it doesn't commute with the stabilizers along the side boundaries. But your stabilizers, which do, do not commute with the stabilizers along the top and bottom boundaries. So it seems like they provided the wrong boundary operators for what they were trying to show.
